# Entity framework code first: many to many to many (>=3)

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to make relation of three tables by introducing the fourth one, like in SQL
but when i run the 'update-database' the error occurs: 'FK ... dbo.ProjectUsersRoles User Id cause cycles or multiple cascade paths'.
I have tried attributes and Fluent Api but result is the same - error. Maybe somebody has had similar error or problem. Here is the code:

```
public class Project
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ProjectUserRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ProjectUserRole> RolesOnProject { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ProjectUserRole> UsersProjects { get; set; }
}
public class ProjectUserRole
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   [Key]
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
   [Key]
   public int RoleId { get; set; }


   public User User { get; set; }

   public Project Project { get; set; }

   public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks so much for help!

Comment: If you take out the reference to `ProjectUserRole` from `Project`, `Role`, and `User` does it work?

Comment: yes, it does. i know this is because of these relations, but why?

Comment: I'm not well-versed in EF. But you do have a `A => B` and `B => A` circular reference issue going on (e.g. `ProjectUserRole` references `User` and `User` references `ProjectUserRole`). Not sure how that all works out in EF, but it looks like it could be a problem. Hopefully someone will give a better explanation of why that doesn't work.

Comment: thanks! i'll check this tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just made it in another direction

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUserRole>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Project)
            .WithMany(x => x.UsersRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUserRole>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithMany(x => x.RolesOnProjects)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectUserRole>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Role)
            .WithMany(x => x.ProjectsUsers)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

hope this will be helpful to somebody. WillDeleteOnCascade points to `linking` table

The problem also may be in Multiple The Same Tables in cascade chain (the table MAY appear only once in cascade chains - and this is not a codefirst but rather MSSQL issue)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to specify the cascadeOnDelete property?
You'll have to do this with fluent configuration, something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.RolesOnProject).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UsersRoles).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UsersProjects).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

This method should be in your DbContext class. As you see I set all of them to not cascade on delete. You'll have to play around with this to make it do what you want it to.

-------*****EDIT*****------

I have not tested this, but if you want cascading delete when deleting Projects I believe this would be the configuration. However, you could consider manually handling cascading deletes.

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(u => u.RolesOnProject).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UsersRoles).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // Changed this..

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany(u => u.UsersProjects).WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

Comment: but what if I want the entities from ProjectUserRole with ProjectId to be deleted for example when I delete correspond Project?

Comment: See the edit. This link might also be of help -> http://alanfeekery.com/2013/10/25/entity-framework-cascade-delete/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood your delete direction.

I just wanted to add one caution. Be aware that doing a delete now might leave unusable data in your database. example: if a User requires an item in the RolesOnProjects list to be usable in the application. Deleting a Role which cascade deletes the ProjectUserRole that a User requires, will make the User invalid (as the RolesOnProjectList is now empty). This might not be an issue for you, but keep it in mind.

(I'm not allowed to add comments yet (don't have 50 rep) so I'll answer here.)

Comment: thanks for an explanation and clarification! and , yes, it is not an issue for me because all three (Project, User and Role are complex) so i dont and wont need these relation without one of them